# IIS 7.5 Configuration settings

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have done XCopy of ASP.NET 2.0 web application and deployed in IIS 7.5 test  server.I have set all necessary basic settings such as IUSR ,NETWORK service account,classic application pool.

I am able to browse home page , but after authentication page is not getting redirected to other page which resides on same application directory.

Could you please kindly let me the possible cause?